# "suite de l'épreuve de" meaning

Tags: vocabulaire

I have been in France for a week. Today I get some draft papers in the laboratory to do my job. There is a note in the draft paper named "suite de l'épreuve de". What does it mean?

P/s: I used google translate tool and get the following result: "following the test". I'm not satisfied with this result.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you give more context ? With only that part, it may mean many different things...

Comment: Actually there are 3 lines as follow: the first line is "Nom et Prenom" which is name, the second line is "Diplome prepare", and the third is what I'm asking.

Comment: Did they have a previous test/experience? It could be for them to keep track of the evolution of the experience that can't be done at once, but on various day, and sub results each time?

Comment: If possible you should asked the people who gave you the papers.They know the context and may be able to answer.

Comment: It's only a draft paper with many blank space to write computations.

Comment: So it might mean you are asked to move on to the next stage of the computation. Context is still insufficient. Google translate is rarely helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A meaningfull sentence could be "suite de l'épreuve de mathématiques (...)", which would mean "next part of the math test".

Here "suite de" have the meaning of "next part of".

Comment: Oh I guess it is an addition paper for students to continue their written exam in case of they don't have enough papers.